# Getting multiple inputs from user with char and integers Java

Tags: java, arrays, user-input

I'm trying to allow the user to put in multiple inputs from the user that contain a char and integers.
Something like this as input: A 26 16 34 9
and output each int added to an array. 
I was thinking I could have the first input as a character and then read the rest as a string which then I separate and put into an array. 
I'm not new to coding but new to java. I've been doing c++ so the syntax is a bit different. 
 This is what I have so far, I haven't set up my array yet for the integers.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program0 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int firstNumber;

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("'A' to enter a number. 'Q' to quit");

        int n = reader.nextInt();
        if (n=='A') {
            //if array is full System.out.println("The list is full!");

            //else
            System.out.println("Integer " + "  " + "has been added to the list");
        }
        else if (n=='Q') {
            System.out.println("List of integers: ");

            System.out.println("Average of all integers in the list: ");

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Action");

        }
        reader.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you specify better how should your input be given? From your question, if I understand well, the user simply type "A" followed by a list of numbers separated by a space. So I would simply read the next line, split it in words (separated by a space) and check if the first word is the letter "A". Here it goes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Program0 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("'A' to enter a number. 'Q' to quit");

        String line = reader.nextLine();
        String[] words = line.split(" ");

        if (words.length > 0 && words[0].equals("A")) {
            //if array is full System.out.println("The list is full!");
            // => I don't understand this part

            //else
            for(int i = 1; i<words.length; i++){
                int integer = Integer.parseInt(words[i]);
                System.out.println("Integer " + integer + " has been added to the list");

                //do your stuff here
            }
        }
        else if (words.length > 0 && words[0].equals("Q")) {
            System.out.println("List of integers: ");

            System.out.println("Average of all integers in the list: ");

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Invalid Action");

        }
        reader.close();
    }

}
```

---

Note that in your solution, you read the next int from your scanner and then try to compare it with the character `'A'`. This will not work because `A` is not an int. If you really want to get the first character from your scanner, you could do:

```
String line = reader.nextLine();
if(line.length() > 0){
    char firstChar = line.charAt(0);
    //do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: The reason I had that part is I want to put all the numbers into an array and if the array is full I want it to notify the user. But this is a good starting point thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

A character is not an int. You cannot read an int to expect something like 'A'. You can read a String and take its first character though. Scanner doesn't offer a convenient method to read the next String and expect it to be only one-character long. You'd need to handle that yourself.

But considering you don't know in advance how many numbers there will be to read, your solution to read the entire line and interpret it entirely, is the better one. That means you can't use nextInt() nor nextDouble() nor next() nor nextWhateverElse().

You need nextLine(), and it will give you the entire line as a String.

Then you can split() the result, and check if the first is one-char-long. Then you can parse all the others as int.

Answer (score 0):

I don't immediately recall how to write this in Java – it's been a bit of a while – but what I'd do is to first separate the string by spaces, then *attempt* to do `ParseInt` on each piece.

If the string *isn't* a valid integer, this method will `throw` an exception, which you can catch.  So:

- If you make it to the next statement, an exception didn't happen, so the value is an integer.
- If, instead, you find yourself in the exception-handler (having caught [only ...] the expected kind of exception, the value is a string.
- Of course, don't "catch" any exception-type other than the `NumberFormatException` that you're expecting.

By the way, it is *perfectly routine* to use exceptions in this way.  Let Java's runtime engine be the authority as to whether it's an integer or not.